# Manually deploying on Ubuntu a Django application made in Visual Studio

Tags: django, django-admin, ubuntu-server

I have installed on the Ubuntu server:

```
apt-get install python-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi
pip install virtualenv
mkdir -p /django/projects/prj01
cd /django/projects/prj01
```

create the virtual environment:

```
virtualenv prj01env
```

activate the virtual environment:

```
source prj01env/bin/activate
```

install django in the virtual environment:

```
pip install django
```

I previously uploaded project folder with winscp
now I copy that project in /django/projects/prj01:

```
cp /home/myuser/prj01/ ./
cd prj01
```

change permissions:

```
chmod +x /django/projects/prj01
chown -R www-data:www-data /django/projects/
```

convert the text file from windows to linux format:

```
dos2unix manage.py
```

Finally I run manage.py

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

And then I receive the follow error message:

```
(prj01env) root@RSR0008:/django/projects/prj01/prj01# ./manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 342, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01/prj01/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
ImportError: cannot import name patterns
```

Anyone can tell me what is wrong with that procedure?

If I create an empty project directly from the server, everything is working fine, but if I copy my project from my windows client, it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you installed Django you probably installed the newest version (1.10) in which this method has been removed ([`patterns` has been deprecated since 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#patterns)), but your project files are from an older version of Django.

Instead of using `patterns` like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
        url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
        url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),   
)
```

You should just use a simple list, like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', index_view, name="main-view"),
    ...
]
```

Alternatively, you could probably get away with installing an older version of Django in your `virtualenv`, though I wouldn't recommend this, unless it is absoluetely necessary.

Comment: My version is 1.10.2

Comment: My urls.py has been modified to:

Comment: `"""
Definition of urls for prj01.
"""

from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app.forms import BootstrapAuthenticationForm

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from prj01 import views
admin.autodiscover()`

Comment: `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', 'app.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', 'app.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^prj01/', include('app.prj01.urls')),
    url(r'^test/', views.test, name='test'),

]`

Comment: When I run the make migration I receive the follow error:

Comment: File "/django/projects/prj01/prj01env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Comment: @Steve, you should change url entries like `url(r'^about', 'app.views.about', name='about')` to `url(r'^about', app.views.about, name='about')`, i.e., passing the actual callable object rather than a string (again, this is something that  was not necessary in older versions of Django, but is in newer versions).